# Customizing Font Issue in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, fonts, styles

In application i have to use custom font. First i create class that extends VerticalFieldManager class. In this class i want to use custom font. I have TTF file (name is AGENCYB.TTF). I kept this file in res/img folder. To load this file i use following code:

```
if (FontManager.getInstance().load("AGENCYB.TTF", "MyFont",
        FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS)
{
   System.out.println("**************************IF SUCCESS*******");
   try
   {
      FontFamily typeface = FontFamily.forName("MyFont");
      myFont = typeface.getFont(Font.BOLD, 50);
      label2.setFont(myFont);
   }
   catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
   {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

But it is not changing font of label field. I implemented code by using this link:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18095/BlackBerry_Java_SDK-Development_Guide--1239696-0730090812-001-6.0-US.pdf

Any idea would be great help.

Thanks

*****************EDIT***************************

```
if (FontManager.getInstance().load("AGENCYB.TTF", "AGENCYB", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS)
```

Comment: Are you missing the code `if (FontManager.getInstance().load("AGENCYB.TTF", "MyFont", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS)` at the start of your Java?  Please be careful when posting your code.  It's difficult to help unless we know exactly what you're using. And **please**, don't use empty `catch` blocks in code that's not working.  If there's an exception thrown, you need to know what it is, and of course, then tell us.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you can't set a font to a container. You should set the font to individual components displaying text, such as LabelFields, Buttons, etc.

Comment: @Nate: thanks nate i used above code while posting i missed that line. will take care of these.

Comment: @Mister: thanks. Can you please give me and example. I set above font to LabelField.

Comment: And still not working? Check what is `FontManager.load` returning. If it is `FontManager.SUCCESS` then the problem must be in the GUI code.

Comment: Code that it returns is 8.

Comment: Is there something like it is taking default font of device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [this is the BlackBerry tutorial I've used for loading custom fonts](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Load_and_use_a_custom_font_899948_11.jsp)

Second of all, I don't see a return code of 8 in any of the values that the API docs says `FontManager.load()` returns.  `SUCCESS` is a value of 0, so you're not *successfully* calling `load()`.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FontManager.html

> **Returns**:  
>   FontManager.SUCCESS if font loads successfully. 
>   FontManager.FONTS_ARRAY_FULL if too many fonts loaded.  
>   FontManager.MISSING_TYPEFACE_NAME if typeface name is invalid. 
>   FontManager.DUPLICATE_NAME if font name is duplicate.  
>   FontManager.DUPLICATE_DATA if font data is duplicate. 
>   FontManager.NO_FONT_DATA if no font data is found.  
>   FontManager.EXCEEDS_LIMIT if font data exceeds 60k in size.  
>   FontManager.MISS_RESOURCE if font file cannot be found.  
>   FontManager.FAILED_TO_LOAD_FILE if font data is invalid or font format is invalid.

When I ran in the debugger on OS 5.0 and 7.1, I saw that `-8` was equal to `FontManager.DUPLICATE_NAME`, but didn't see any code equal to `8`.

Also, did you generate this font file yourself (AGENCYB.TTF)?  Because your code is asking for a font named **MyFont** in the AGENCYB.TTF file.  I wouldn't expect a font to actually be named **MyFont** unless it was somebody writing a *Hello World* program (and homemade .ttf file).

If this is a custom font, provided by a 3rd-party font library, or bought from someone else, I would expect the font names to be something other than **MyFont**, which is what they have in the BlackBerry sample that you probably copied your code from.

So, double-check that, and let us know if it's still not working.

---

**Update:** since it looks like you also fail when you use the string `"AGENCYB"` in your code, I think the problem is that you're using the wrong font name.  Even though the file is `AGENCYB.TTF`, I bet the font name *inside* that file is **not** `AGENCYB`.  Is this the same file that you find in Windows under `C:\Windows\fonts`?  If so, you can use Windows (7, at least) to look at the font file.

Just double-click the .ttf file in Windows Explorer, and it should give you a preview, that shows the proper font name.  **That** name is the name you use in the **two** java calls, where the sample code has `"MyFont"`.  In this case, you see that the font name is probably `"Agency FB"`.  Try that.

[image]

---

**Update 2:**  I also tried loading the **Agency FB** font from the `AGENCYR.TTF` file that can be found in `C:\windows\Fonts\AGENCYR.TTF` on a Windows 7 machine.  This exact code worked for me on a 5.0 8900 simulator:

```
  int result = FontManager.getInstance().load("AGENCYR.TTF", "Agency FB", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT);

  if (result == FontManager.SUCCESS)
  {
     try 
     {
        FontFamily typeface = FontFamily.forName("Agency FB");
        Font myFont = typeface.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 50);
        helloWorld.setFont(myFont); 
     }
     catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
     {
     }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes it is returning me -8. I apoligize for this. and i m using Blackberry OS 7.1. I am testing application on simulator. In place of "MyFont" i used file name(AGENCYB)           **if (FontManager.getInstance().load("AGENCYB.TTF", "AGENCYB", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS).  ***   And "AGENCYB.TTF" i kept this file in res folder.

Comment: @soft, I'm not sure I understand.  Did you try something else, instead of passing the string `"MyFont"`?  If so, **exactly** what did you try?  Also, if you have tried more than one thing, please use the **edit** link under your question, and add that information, so everyone can easily see it.  Thanks!

Comment: @soft, thank you for updating your question.  I have posted additional information in my answer above.

Comment: I tried with this             if(FontManager.getInstance().load("AGENCYR.TTF","Agency FB",FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT)==FontManager.SUCCESS)
 its not working. Nate one more thing i download hindi file and name of file is AMAA_Regular.ttf and i used"AMAA_Regular" in place of "MyFont" it works for first time after that i run this again not wrking.

Comment: @soft, it's harder to help you when you keep changing the code you're using.  The font name **Agency FB** is in the file `AGENCYB.TTF`.  If you use the file `AGENCYR.TTF`, you're going to have to find out what the correct font name is for that file.  I show, in my update above, how you can use Windows to inspect the .ttf file, and discover the proper font name inside.   Regarding your second problem, if it fails the second time, just don't load the font more than once.  If you call `typeface.getFont()`, you should just store that value in a `Font` member variable, and reuse it the 2nd time.

Comment: AGENCYR.TTF this is another file that i used to check and inside this file font name is Agency FB. I double click on file to view .TTF file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22828/discussion-between-soft-and-nate)

Comment: I updated my answer again with the **exact** code I'm using, to successfully load **Agency FB** from the `AGENCYR.TTF` file that comes with Windows 7.  If you are using a different `AGENCYR.TTF` file, you probably need to provide a link to your version in the question, so we can test it.  Maybe there's something wrong with your .ttf file.  If it's still not working, please tell us **what** is not working.  `FontManager.load()` gives you a return code.  What code is it giving you?  Are you seeing exceptions thrown?

Comment: :-Lots of thanks for this great help..yesterday i load file successfully. bt the problem was it was working for me for first time. Then u told me to dnt download file for second time. But if i will run application again, then i need to download file again. For this today, after downloading file i unload that file using:    
 FontManager.getInstance().unload("Agency FB"); I am successfully able to customize font with your help. thanks

Comment: @Nate i am also facing same issue. i had tried the above solution and app run with font for first time only after that always i am getting -8 code while i try to load the font.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you should check if the font desired is already loaded so it gives you a -8 or the success int and thats it!

Answer (score 0):

LabelField lbl = new LabelField("This is test Label");

// IF font is already loaded then use the following

```
   if(FontManager.getInstance().load("TickingTimebombBB_ital.ttf", "Ticking Timebomb BB", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.DUPLICATE_NAME){
         Logger.debug("---font already loaded-----");
            try 
            {
                System.out.println("---load once more---");
                FontFamily typeface = FontFamily.forName("Ticking Timebomb BB");
                Font myFont = typeface.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 80);
                lbl.setFont(myFont); 
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                Logger.error("---error-----"+e.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

and if the font is not already loaded then use the following

```
else if(FontManager.getInstance().load("TickingTimebombBB_ital.ttf", "Ticking Timebomb BB", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS) {
            try 
            {
                Logger.debug("---load first time---");
                FontFamily typeface = FontFamily.forName("Ticking Timebomb BB");
                Font myFont = typeface.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 80);
                lbl.setFont(myFont); 
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                Logger.error("---error-----"+e.getMessage());
            }

    }
```